# how to detect page close in firefox by alt+f4, exit, click X

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, detect

sorry if this is repeated question, but unable to get solution to detect page close in Firefox, already tried all possibility, but not work,

I have a main page, sub page with sub menu, in main page having `BODY onbeforeunload="showLoading();"` to check the user session,

I need to check whether the page is close unexpectly by click 'X', alt+f4, File -> Exit,
below is the code what I did, but its only working fine in IE, not in Firefox

```
    showLoading() {
    if((window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.altKey) || (window.event.ctrlKey) || ((window.event.clientY < 129) && (window.event.clientY>107))) {
        sendSilentLogoff();
        alert("You have been logged out");      
    }else{
                 showProgress();
            }
    }
```

any one can help on this,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. That means, there is no way for ECMAscript code to determine *how* or *why* a document gets *closed* / *unloaded*.

You already mentioned your best shot, that is the `onbeforeunload` event handler, which you should attach to the `window object`.

That event will take care of you for the most part, of course this can't help you either if the meteor hits or apocalyptic riders come along or the client will just crash for no reason.